# Can we change the definition of a limit of a sequence and keep the same set of theorems?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

A sequence $\{a_n\}$ is said to converge to a $a$ if and only if for any given $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $$|a_n-a|<\epsilon$$
for all $n\ge N$.

Can we change the definition to

> For a given $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb N$:$$n \ge N \implies |a_n-a|\le \epsilon$$

and still keep the same set of theorems?  The two definitions seem equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading correctly, the only difference between definition I and definition II is that definition I uses $<\epsilon$, and definition II uses $\leq\epsilon$.

They are equivalent. Suppose we have definition I, i.e., for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find an $N$ satisfying the $<\epsilon$ condition. Then it of course also satisfies the $\leq\epsilon$ condition, so we have definition II. Conversely, suppose we have definition II. For any $\epsilon>0$ take the $N$ that satisfies the $\leq\frac\epsilon2$ condition (guaranteed because definition II assures an $N$ can be found for any $\epsilon>0$), and it then satisfies the $<\epsilon$ condition, so we have definition I.